# Gerrit workflow

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, gerrit

I have been following a version of the branching model found on [nvie.com](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). Essentially I branch from a stable point on the development branch, work on a feature and then merge back in - fixing any merge conflicts that arise and giving a detailed overview of what this feature entails.

I've now started using Gerrit and this model isn't working. Merging a feature branch to the dev branch result in only the commit message appearing on Gerrit. Assuming this is by design what is the recommended workflow for Gerrit?

I've searched up and down for answers and got zilch outside of two imperfect solutions:

- squashed commits (`git merge --squash`)

  Not ideal as it doesn't associate with original branch and results in an
  outrageously long commit message
- rebases on dev. (`git rebase [dev]`)

  Not ideal as it involves either lots of small commit message being placed
  on dev or a loss of granularity (and history) in the feature branch if
  I squash some commit messages.

All help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "*Merging a feature branch to the dev branch result in only the commit message appearing on Gerrit*"? At work we use Gerrit with feature branches and don't see the problem you are describing.

Comment: is it possible to use continues integration, so committing on development branch?

Comment: When I merge I get a merge commit (like anyone). Pushing this however only shows the commit message (normally the first item/gile in a review) on Gerrit...not the merged files. The only thing I know of that could be different to other places is my development branches font go through Gerrit but rather directly i.e. ``git push origin feature_x`` rather than ``git push origin HEAD:refs/for/feature_x``

Comment: Assuming by CI uou mean integrating to dev regularly, I've found that doesn't really work when working on a large feature. Submitting only one part of a change set tends to break tests which is something I wouldn't class as acceptable :/

Comment: Stephenfin, I have been using the nvie model with gerrit and i don't see a problem with merging in feature branches to main trunk as long as the feature branch is covering all the requirement of Definition of Done. 
It is true that gerrit is not showing the complete diff against one branch over another, but we haven't seen this as a problem in my org.

Comment: You should be rebasing your changes on top of the development branch before you merge the feature branch in.

Comment: @Jeff Ideally yes - however the remote Git repo I push to does not allow force pushes. If I rebase I can't "save" these changes by pushing to the remote. Instead, I tend to merge *from* dev (to synchronise) before I merge *into* dev

Comment: Bit confused, you shouldn't need to force push as you aren't changing history.

Comment: I'm taking my changes from the branch, that were based on an old version of dev (HEAD~5 for example), and replaying them on top of the current dev HEAD. Far as I know the branch on remote can't be fast-forwarded with this kind of change?

Comment: I know it's an old question but feel free to check out my related improvement: [stackoverflow.com/a/65724774...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65724774/4241078)

Answer (score 0):

In gerrit you will not see files affected if it is a merge commit [merging one branch into another which is not a fast forward , creates merge commit]. You can verify your commit by pulling it to local repo [if you try to cherry-pick it , it will show you error] or check the diff in gitweb.

Comment: So the merge still happens and the code just doesn't show because it's a merge? If this is the case what use is Gerrit? You can't code review something you can't see?

Comment: That's not the case you can still review your merge commits in gerrit. For that you need to click on gitweb link. You will get this link same row in which the patchset number is mentioned. Something like this : " Patch Set 1    (gitweb) " . CLick on the gitweb link and then select diff.

Comment: regarding your first query"So   ... If this is the case what use is Gerrit?"  Basically merge commit is a combination of different commits, i.e. it includes more than one commits because of which you dont see code for merge commits. Also unlike simple commit , merge commit has two parents.

Comment: There is no gitweb link on my version of Gerrit. I suspect this is because I don't use gitweb or have the gitweb plugin. Your point of two parents does make sense however - that would explain why only the commit message is shown.

Comment: Then you need to pull that merge commit to local repo for review. Once you pull that change you can execute git commands to check the diff.